# Having issue with EmguCV

Tags: c#, deployment, emgucv

I'm trying to create a program for webcam capture, in which I followed the online tutorial. I was able to debug it and deploy the program, but when I installed it on my PC the program failed to execute then gave an error message as follows

```
 Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. 
 The type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
```

Has any one came across this kind of error? Please assist.
Thanks

Comment: To use emguCV you have to have all required dll's at the same directory as the executable(`ex: bin/debug`). Please check.

Comment: Also verify that you use the same architecture (x64 dlls for x64 compiled solution, x86 otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error in EmguCV which is explained in détails in the [Download and Installation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.) page. Most of the time, people doesn't have the MSVCRT installed on the dev or deployment machine.

It can also be that the DLL are not present in the debug folder, or in your case, in the deployed folder.